# Strange behaviour of MouseEvent.movementX & Y on Windows (Mac OS works fine)

Tags: javascript, html, windows, macos, mouseevent

I've created a sample code demonstrating how e.movementX & e.movementY are behaving in different ways on Windows and Mac OS. I assume that movementX & Y should follow perfectly the mouse movement in this sample (as happens in Mac OS).

How the sample works:

- mouse movement sets the circle top & left to clientY & clientX
- if mouse button is pressed then it relies on movementX & movementY

https://codepen.io/wagnerpaz/pen/jOygvQP?editors=1111

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="circle"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
#circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```
let pressed = false;

document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
  pressed = true;
});

document.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
  pressed = false;
});

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  const circle = document.getElementById('circle');
  if(!pressed) {
    circle.style.top = e.clientY - 25 + 'px';
    circle.style.left = e.clientX - 25 + 'px';
  }
  else {
    const currentTop = parseInt(circle.style.top.replace('px', ''));
    const currentLeft = parseInt(circle.style.left.replace('px', ''));
    circle.style.top = currentTop + e.movementY + 'px';
    circle.style.left = currentLeft + e.movementX + 'px';
  }
});
```

How can I make Windows follow mouse movement perfectly like Mac OS does?